# Prebuilt sparc bare metal cross compiler not working

Tags: sparc

Downloaded a prebuilt cross compiler [sparc-elf-4.2.2](https://www.gaisler.com/anonftp/bcc/bin/linux/) and has set the PATH to sparc-elf-4.4.4/bin after which i ran `sparc-elf-gcc -o matrixmul matrixmul.c` on the terminal only to find the following response

```
/home/root/sparc-elf-4.4.2/bin/sparc-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea as to why this response .

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Turned out that that my OS is a 64-Bit Ubuntu System and the compiler is a 32-Bit program.
I followed the instructions given here https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit :

> To run a 32-bit executable file on a 64-bit multi-architecture Ubuntu
> system, you have to add the i386 architecture and install the three
> library packages libc6:i386, libncurses5:i386, and libstdc++6:i386:

> *sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386*
> Or if you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or below, use this:

> *echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch*
> Then:

> *sudo apt-get update*
> *sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386*
> If fails, do also

> *sudo apt-get install multiarch-support*
> After these steps, you should be able to run the 32-bit application:

> *./example32bitprogram*